# LINQ error - The method 'Sum' is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am having following linq -

```
var quantity = (from p in context.StoreInventory
                         where p.BookId== BookId
                                && p.StoreAddress == StoreAddress
                         select p).Sum(i => i.Quantity);
```

I am getting error -

> The method 'Sum' is not supported

Can anyone tell me the reason and required changes.

Comment: Is it linq to entities ? Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var quantity = (from p in context.StoreInventory
                         where p.BookId== BookId
                                && p.StoreAddress == StoreAddress
                         select p.Quantity).Sum();
```

This should work - the sum is performed on `'Quality'` column, which is taken using `select` statement. That's because `Sum(expression)` is not supported by LINQ to Entities, but standard `Sum()` is.

Whole work should be done by database, so no rows will be retrieved by application - just single number.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, which does not brings calculation to memory

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) before you call Sum to convert the query to collection.

```
var quantity = (from p in context.StoreInventory
                         where p.BookId== BookId
                                && p.StoreAddress == StoreAddress
                         select p).ToList().Sum(i => i.Quantity);
```

**Edit**: This will bring all the row and will apply the sum which is not efficient way of doing. As you need to sum up quantity you can select quanity instead of row.

```
var quantity = (from p in context.StoreInventory
                         where p.BookId== BookId
                                && p.StoreAddress == StoreAddress
                         select p.Quantity).Sum();
```

Comment: This will force to get all rows from database and than calculate the sum by application.